# Can higher G-theory of Noetherian schemes be computed by derived categories?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, triangulated-categories, abelian-categories

Recently I learned from the Stacks project that for every abelian category ${\mathcal A}$, there is a natural isomorphism $K_0({\mathcal A})\cong K_0(D^{b}(\mathcal A))$.
When we set $\mathcal A$ to be the abelian category $M(X)$ of coherent sheaves on a Noetherian scheme $X$,we get that $G_0(X)\cong K_0(D^{b}(M(X)))$.
Is it true that $K_i({\mathcal A})\cong K_i(D^{b}({\mathcal A}))$ for every abelian category ${\mathcal A}$ and $i\geq 0$?
I saw in Amnon Neeman’s 1997 paper K-theory for Triangulated Categories I(A):Homological Functors that my question was answered in the affirmative on page 341,as Theorem 7.1.
But I am new to the K-theory of triangulated categories.
So I would like to confirm that this is true.
Another question is, assuming $K_i({\mathcal A})\cong K_i(D^{b}({\mathcal A}))$ for every abelian category ${\mathcal A}$ and $i\geq 0$, does this isomorphism provide a practical method of computing the higher $G$-theory of a Noetherian scheme?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah this is true, as Neeman explains this follows from his more general theorem of the heart for the bounded derived category with the standard t-structure.

You can see a modern treatment ( with a shorter proof in the language of $\infty$-categories ) in Barwick's paper

*Barwick, Clark*, [**On exact (\infty)-categories and the theorem of the heart**](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X15007447), Compos. Math. 151, No. 11, 2160-2186 (2015). [ZBL1333.19003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1333.19003).

There, in the first appendix, Barwick discusses applications of this theorem to calculating the G-theory of noetherian schemes, namely one of the claims is that the G-theory of such scheme coincides with the K-theory of an abelian category of Cohen–Macaulay complexes.

Comment: Is there a way to compute the K-theory of an abelian category of Cohen-Macaulay complexes for a normal variety? I am trying to compute the higher $G$-theory of a simplicial toric variety. Thanks.